# Open all html files from a folder with browser in Python enviroment

Tags: python, file, browser

I have a folder with several huge html files.
I would like to have a script to open them all html files from the defined folder with a standard browser in windows. Each html file should be open in a new tab.

I have no code, because i could not find any similar to that, what i need.

Answer (score 2):

something like this

```
import os
import webbrowser


def open_files_in_browser(folder_name):
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_name):
        if filename.endswith(".html") or filename.endswith(".htm"):
            webbrowser.open_new_tab(os.path.join(folder_name, filename))


open_files_in_browser('/your_folder/goes_here')
```

Answer (score 1):

So this works if html files are in the same dir as the script with code. I used `os.listdir('files')` to open files from sub directory, but it opened them in new windows of Internet Explorer. I don't know maybe its a Windows 10 issue.

```
from glob import glob
import webbrowser

for file in glob('*.html'):
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(file)
```

For me files are opened in new tabs in Firefox.

Hope it helps. More about `webbrowser` is in the link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('test.html')
```

Comment: That's not even an answer and it got upvoted :|